# Json payload hashing in OSB 12C REST API

Tags: json, rest, weblogic12c, soa, osb

We are doing a JSON payload hashing for our rest services to verify "no man in the middle". we request the service consumer to hash the entire payload in the POST operation and send the hash value in the header. in OSB layer once we receive the payload we will generate the hash value of the payload received and compare with the hash value sent in headers.
the issue is when the json payload is received weblogic is sorting the json payload, meaning the sequence of the elements is getting changed in OSB layer. tried to get issue resolved from Oralce support, but they have assigned the same to development team to find a fix.
looking for support on the below

1. how to avoid the automatic json payload sequencing in weblogic layer.
2. other best alternative methods for hashing the payloads to acheive "no man in the middle"

Thanks,
Sandeep.

I tried to add the below configuration as updated by oracle support but it did not work

JVM property added
JVM property -DJsonObject.KeepJsonKeyOrder=true

WebLogic Admin console -> click on environment -> servers -> soa_server -> Configuration -> Server Start
and add the startup options for the SOA server in the Arguments field

SOA 12C patch applied
30702934: Sjson Parser should keep the sequence of Json keys